# Wireguard - Disable all internet traffic but only allow to same VPC servers in AWS

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, wireguard

I have configured Wireguard in AWS and I was able to connect to the server from client. But what I want is, I don't want to route all internet traffic to Wireguard, so after connect VPN my public IP should be from ISP not from AWS server. But I should be able to connect to the other servers in the same VPC which I used to create the Wireguard server. This same thing is working out of the box from OpenVPN, but I don't know how to configure the same thing in Wireguard.

Here is my wg0.conf:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.50.0.1
SaveConfig = false
PrivateKey = <private_key>
ListenPort = 54321
PostUp   = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE;

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public_key>
PresharedKey = <preshared_key>
AllowedIPs = 10.50.0.2/32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` in your *client* conf. Instead you should have only the VPN IP of the server and the subnet ID of its LAN subnet.

Say it's `192.168.123.0/24`, then it should be:

```
AllowedIPs = 10.50.0.1, 192.168.123.0/24
```

P.S. The `AllowedIPs=` in your pasted *server* conf is fine.

Comment: This worked.. Thanks